# How do I declare typings in Typescript of a function which returns a result of one of its callbacks?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I have a `mapResponse` function that takes another function (caller) and a mapper function. The result of the function should be a 3rd function which is a combination of the provided callbacks: it should take parameters of the caller but returns the result of the mapper.

The caller can result in Promise, so the Promise should be unpacked before the mapper gets his parameters.

So my question is not the implementation (which is done already) but the typings. How can I describe such behaviour with the Typescript declarations?

```js
export function mapResponse<
  Caller extends (...args: any[]) => unknown,
  Mapper extends <R>(response: Unpacked<ReturnType<Caller>>) => R
>(
  caller: Caller,
  mapper: Mapper
): (...args: Parameters<Caller>) => ReturnType<Mapper> {
  return (...args: Parameters<Caller>) => {
    const res = caller(...args) as Unpacked<ReturnType<Caller>>
    if (res instanceof Promise) {
      return res.then(mapper) as ReturnType<Mapper>
    }
    return mapper(res)
  }
}
```

Here is the `Unpacked` declaration if anyone needs it:

```js
export type Unpacked<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? U : T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U
  ? U : T extends Promise<infer U>
  ? U : T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would declare function as follows:

```typescript
type Unpacked<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;

declare function mapResponse
    <
        TCaller extends (...args: any[]) => any,
        TMapper extends (input: Unpacked<ReturnType<TCaller>>) => any
    >(caller: TCaller, mapper: TMapper):
        TMapper extends (input: Unpacked<ReturnType<TCaller>>) => infer R ? (...args: Parameters<TCaller>) => R : never;


const func1 = mapResponse((a: number, b: number) => a + b, sum => sum.toString()); // (a: number, b: number) => string
const func2 = mapResponse((a: number, b: number) => Promise.resolve(a + b), sum => sum.toString()); // (a: number, b: number) => string
```

Difference compared to your example is that `TMapper` has to have `extends` definition on the right side as well, in order to `infer R` correctly.

TypeScript playground example here: https://tsplay.dev/wOav6m